# Как программно получить список всех свойств устройства в Device Manager'e?

Tags: c#, c++, wmi

Привет всем!

Возникла идея написать приложение на подобии [USBDeview](http://nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) (приложение, отображающее все подключенные на данный момент USB девайсы). Хочу также реализовать функционал включения/выключения USB устройства по расписанию (USBDeview тоже так умеет). Все манипуляции провожу через запросы к WMI . Столкнулся с рядом проблем:

1. При подключении нового USB устройства появляются два девайса - USB Mass Storage Device и Disk Drive. Какое из включать/выключать, чтобы USB устройство правильно отключилось?
2. Запрос "select * from Win32_PnpEntity" возвращает довольно скудный набор свойств (например отсутствуют нужные мне параметры, такие как Matching device Id, Class, Is connected и т.д. - все эти параметры есть в Device Manager'e во вкладке Details). Отсюда вытекает вопрос. Как отобразить ВСЕ свойства, которые есть в Device Manager'e?
   Небольшой пример кода на C#:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           ManagementObjectCollection collection;
            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_PnpEntity"))
                collection = searcher.Get();
```

`foreach (var device in collection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("===================================");
            foreach (var prop in device.Properties)
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0} : {1}", prop.Name, prop.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("===================================");
        }

        collection.Dispose();

        Console.Read();
    }`

При подключении флешки появляется два новых устройства:

Disk Drive: 
[image: diskdrive]

USB Mass Storage Device:
[image: usb]

Мне же нужно получить список этих свойств: 
[image: devicemanager]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении мне идти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> При подключении нового USB устройства появляются два девайса - USB
>   Mass Storage Device и Disk Drive. Какое из включать/выключать, чтобы
>   USB устройство правильно отключилось?

Я полагаю, USB Mass Storage Device, т.к. Disk Drive является для него дочерним устройством, и отключается автоматически

> Как отобразить ВСЕ свойства, которые есть в Device Manager'e?

Не знаю насчет "все", но довольно много свойств можно получить с помощью Setup API. Функция на C++ для вывода всех свойств по заданному ID устройства:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"Setupapi.lib")

#include <Windows.h>
#include <Setupapi.h>
#include <winusb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Devpkey.h>
#include <iostream>

void ErrorMes(LPTSTR lpszFunction) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    // Display the error message and exit the process

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    wprintf(L"%s failed with error %d: %s", 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);     

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);

}


/*Вывод информации об устройстве с указанным InstanceID*/
BOOL PrintDevice(wchar_t* id)
{
    unsigned index;
    HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData;
    TCHAR id_upper[1024]=L"";
    TCHAR buf[1024]=L"";    
    DEVPROPTYPE dpt=0;  
    DEVPROPKEY arr[100];
    DWORD count=0;

    for(int i=0;i<wcslen(id);i++){
        id_upper[i]=toupper(id[i]);//преобразование в заглавные буквы
    }       

    // List all connected devices
    hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES);
    for (index = 0; ; index++) {
        DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(DeviceInfoData);
        if (!SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, index, &DeviceInfoData)) {
            return FALSE;     // no match
        }

        BOOL res=SetupDiGetDeviceProperty(hDevInfo,&DeviceInfoData,
                        &DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId,&dpt,(PBYTE)buf,1000,NULL,0);
            if(res==FALSE)continue; 


        if(wcscmp(buf,id_upper)==0){
            //устройство найдено
            res=SetupDiGetDeviceProperty(hDevInfo,&DeviceInfoData,
                        &DEVPKEY_Device_DeviceDesc,&dpt,(PBYTE)buf,1000,NULL,0);

            //вывод названия устройства
            if(res==FALSE)ErrorMes(L"SetupDiGetDeviceProperty");
            else wprintf(L"* %s's properties: *\n\n ",buf); 

            //получение свойств
            res=SetupDiGetDevicePropertyKeys(hDevInfo,&DeviceInfoData,arr,100,&count,0);
            if(res==FALSE)ErrorMes(L"SetupDiGetDevicePropertyKeys");

            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)//вывод всех свойств
            {
                res=SetupDiGetDeviceProperty(hDevInfo,&DeviceInfoData,
                    &arr[i],&dpt,(PBYTE)buf,1000,NULL,0);//запрос свойства

                if(res==FALSE){ErrorMes(L"SetupDiGetDeviceProperty");continue;} 

                //вывод DEVPROPKEY
                wprintf(L"{%08lX-%04hX-%04hX-%02hhX%02hhX-%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX; %3d}: ",
                arr[i].fmtid.Data1, arr[i].fmtid.Data2, arr[i].fmtid.Data3, 
                arr[i].fmtid.Data4[0], arr[i].fmtid.Data4[1], arr[i].fmtid.Data4[2], arr[i].fmtid.Data4[3],
                arr[i].fmtid.Data4[4], arr[i].fmtid.Data4[5], arr[i].fmtid.Data4[6], arr[i].fmtid.Data4[7],
                arr[i].pid);

                //вывод типа и значения свойства
                switch (dpt)
                {
                    case DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING:wprintf(L"String   \t%s\n ",buf);  break;      
                    case DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING_LIST:wprintf(L"Strings \tFirst line: %s\n ",buf);break;    
                    case DEVPROP_TYPE_BOOLEAN:wprintf(L"Bool     \t%d\n ",(bool)*((LPBYTE)(&buf)));break;
                    case DEVPROP_TYPE_UINT16:wprintf(L"%Uint16    \t%d\n ",*((LPWORD)(&buf)));break;
                    case DEVPROP_TYPE_UINT32:wprintf(L"Uint     \t%d\n ",*((LPUINT)(&buf)));break;
                    case DEVPROP_TYPE_GUID:
                        wprintf(L"GUID   \t{%08lX-%04hX-%04hX-%02hhX%02hhX-%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX}\n ",
                            (*((GUID*)(&buf))).Data1, (*((GUID*)(&buf))).Data2, (*((GUID*)(&buf))).Data3, 
                            (*((GUID*)(&buf))).Data4[0], (*((GUID*)(&buf))).Data4[1], (*((GUID*)(&buf))).Data4[2], 
                            (*((GUID*)(&buf))).Data4[3], (*((GUID*)(&buf))).Data4[4], (*((GUID*)(&buf))).Data4[5], 
                            (*((GUID*)(&buf))).Data4[6], (*((GUID*)(&buf))).Data4[7]);

                        break;
                    case DEVPROP_TYPE_BINARY:wprintf(L"(Binary data)\n ");break;

                    default:wprintf(L"Other    \tType: 0x%x\n ",(int)dpt);
                    break;
                }                           

            }           

            SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);
            return TRUE;
        }//end if


    }//end for

    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);
    return FALSE;//устройство не найдено
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");

    PrintDevice(L"USB\\VID_046E&PID_5505\\5&15C311E1&0&6");        

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Пример вывода:

```
* Составное USB устройство's properties: *

 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;   2}: String    Составное USB устройство
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;   3}: Strings   First line: USB\VID_046E&PID_5505&REV_0100
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;   4}: Strings   First line: USB\DevClass_00&SubClass_00&Prot_00
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;   6}: String    usbccgp
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;   9}: String    USB
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;  10}: GUID      {36FC9E60-C465-11CF-8056-444553540000}
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;  11}: String    {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}\0009
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;  12}: Uint      0
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;  13}: String    (Стандартный USB хост-контроллер)
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;  15}: String    Port_#0006.Hub_#0003
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;  16}: String    \Device\USBPDO-6
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;  17}: Uint      132
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;  21}: GUID      {9D7DEBBC-C85D-11D1-9EB4-006008C3A19A}
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;  22}: Uint      15
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;  23}: Uint      0
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;  24}: String    USB
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;  30}: Uint      6
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;  32}: (Binary data)
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;  33}: Uint      3
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;  34}: Uint      3
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;  36}: Uint      0
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;  38}: GUID      {23447943-B752-11E7-B8FD-806E6F6E6963}
 {B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC;  10}: String    Составное USB устройство
 {78C34FC8-104A-4ACA-9EA4-524D52996E57; 256}: String    USB\VID_046E&PID_5505\5&15C311E1&0&6
 {4340A6C5-93FA-4706-972C-7B648008A5A7;   2}: Uint      25182218
 {4340A6C5-93FA-4706-972C-7B648008A5A7;   3}: Uint      0
 {4340A6C5-93FA-4706-972C-7B648008A5A7;   7}: Strings   First line: USB\VID_046E&PID_5505&MI_00\6&157c6e38&0&0000
 {4340A6C5-93FA-4706-972C-7B648008A5A7;   8}: String    USB\ROOT_HUB30\4&1ed8c4ae&0&0
 {4340A6C5-93FA-4706-972C-7B648008A5A7;   9}: Strings   First line: USB\VID_046E&PID_5505&MI_00\6&157c6e38&0&0000
 {4340A6C5-93FA-4706-972C-7B648008A5A7;  10}: Strings   First line: USB\VID_09DA&PID_000A\5&15c311e1&0&3
 {AFD97640-86A3-4210-B67C-289C41AABE55;   2}: Bool      0
 {8C7ED206-3F8A-4827-B3AB-AE9E1FAEFC6C;   2}: GUID      {23447943-B752-11E7-B8FD-806E6F6E6963}
 {540B947E-8B40-45BC-A8A2-6A0B894CBDA2;   5}: Bool      1
 {540B947E-8B40-45BC-A8A2-6A0B894CBDA2;   6}: Bool      0
 {83DA6326-97A6-4088-9453-A1923F573B29;  15}: Bool      1
 {540B947E-8B40-45BC-A8A2-6A0B894CBDA2;  16}: Bool      0
 {540B947E-8B40-45BC-A8A2-6A0B894CBDA2;   8}: Uint      2026182162
 {8C7ED206-3F8A-4827-B3AB-AE9E1FAEFC6C;   4}: Bool      0
 {540B947E-8B40-45BC-A8A2-6A0B894CBDA2;  14}: Strings   First line: \Driver\usbccgp
 {3464F7A4-2444-40B1-980A-E0903CB6D912;  10}: Uint      3
 {540B947E-8B40-45BC-A8A2-6A0B894CBDA2;   4}: String    USB Multimedia Keyboard
 {540B947E-8B40-45BC-A8A2-6A0B894CBDA2;   7}: String    usb.inf:USB\COMPOSITE,Composite.Dev.NT
 {540B947E-8B40-45BC-A8A2-6A0B894CBDA2;   9}: (Binary data)
 {540B947E-8B40-45BC-A8A2-6A0B894CBDA2;  10}: String    \_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06
 {80497100-8C73-48B9-AAD9-CE387E19C56E;   6}: Uint      0
 {80497100-8C73-48B9-AAD9-CE387E19C56E;   7}: Other     Type: 0x9
 {83DA6326-97A6-4088-9453-A1923F573B29;   3}: String    usb.inf:392c3d53461eda3a:Composite.Dev.NT:10.0.15063.674:USB\COMPOSITE
 {83DA6326-97A6-4088-9453-A1923F573B29;  10}: String    USB\ROOT_HUB30\4&1ed8c4ae&0&0
 {83DA6326-97A6-4088-9453-A1923F573B29; 100}: Other     Type: 0x10
 {83DA6326-97A6-4088-9453-A1923F573B29; 101}: Other     Type: 0x10
 {83DA6326-97A6-4088-9453-A1923F573B29; 102}: Other     Type: 0x10
 {A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0;  37}: Strings   First line: PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1400)#USBROOT(0)#USB(6)
 {A8B865DD-2E3D-4094-AD97-E593A70C75D6;   2}: Other     Type: 0x10
 {A8B865DD-2E3D-4094-AD97-E593A70C75D6;   3}: String    10.0.15063.674
 {A8B865DD-2E3D-4094-AD97-E593A70C75D6;   4}: String    USB Composite Device
 {A8B865DD-2E3D-4094-AD97-E593A70C75D6;   5}: String    usb.inf
 {A8B865DD-2E3D-4094-AD97-E593A70C75D6;   6}: String    Composite.Dev.NT
 {A8B865DD-2E3D-4094-AD97-E593A70C75D6;   8}: String    USB\COMPOSITE
 {A8B865DD-2E3D-4094-AD97-E593A70C75D6;   9}: String    Microsoft
 {A8B865DD-2E3D-4094-AD97-E593A70C75D6;  14}: Uint      16719875
 Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Свойства определяются по значениям `DEVPROPKEY`. Чтобы понять, что это за свойство, нужно сравнить его с константами из Devpkey.h (например, Matching Device ID - это `DEVPKEY_Device_MatchingDeviceId`).

Comment: спасибо огромное :)