# Получить ID устройства в строковом значении

Tags: c++, linux, c

Есть ли возможность получить строковое значение ID устройств? на скриншоте ниже выделено, что конкретно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересует получение под разные ОС, но в приоритете(желательно прям найти способ ) ) под linux. Под windows тоже можно, но не столь важно. 
P.S.: про lspci знаю, однако она выдает коды производителя и устройства отдельно, интересует таки строковое значение.

Comment: lspci -nnk
вот тут более развернутый ответ есть: https://askubuntu.com/questions/31618/how-can-i-find-my-hardware-details

Comment: @zersh я попробовал Вашу команду, но она выдаёт немного не то. Строки, соответствующей скриншоту не выдаёт. Прочту развернутый ответ подробнее, может там будет информация, однако беглый просмотр её не выявил.

Comment: вам что, какая-то особая программа нужна, чтобы дописать перед идентификатором производителя символы `ven_`, а перед идентификатором устройства символы `dev_`?

Comment: @alexander barakin не всегда hardware id соответствует тому,  что на скриншоте. Как будет время - прикреплю другие скриншоты.

Comment: "*Строки, соответствующей скриншоту не выдаёт*" - А почему вы думаете, что должно? Строка на скриншоте - специфичный для Windows идентификатор, соответствующий пути к ветке в ключе реестра `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum`. Откуда ему взяться в других ОС?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight хм, увы, я этого не знал, думал, что идентификатор такого вида уместен в общем виде для физического устройства, а не для ОС. Для Windows я успешно сгенерировал подобный список...очень жаль, что нет возможности получить такую строку:)

Comment: @Range в Linux все является файлом, устройства тоже представлены виртуальными файлами в каталоге /dev/. Соответственно, и список их можно получить обычными методами работы с файлами.

Comment: Судя по числам, у вас Acer laptop, а у клавиатуры PS/2 идентификатора нет, если я правильно помню спецификации. http://www.mcamafia.de/pdf/ibm_hitrc07.pdf

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, первый комментарий правильный, а вот со вторым я не могу согласиться. Какое отношение имеет модель устройтв в ОС (абстрактная!) к реальному железу? То, что вы видите в */dev/* в подавляющем большинстве случаев не имеет отношения непосредственно к железу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строка на скриншоте - это специфичный для Windows [Hardware ID](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/hardware-ids), т.е. определенная драйвером устройства строка, уникально идентифицирующая данный тип устройства в системе. Эта строка также иногда совпадает с DeviceID, который соответствует пути к ветке реестра с конфигурацией данного типа устройств в разделе `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum`. (Такой ID имеет формат `<enumerator>\<enumerator-specific-device-ID>`). Несмотря на название, Hardware ID имеет мало отношения к реальному железу: он служит лишь для установления соответствия устройства inf-файлу его драйвера. Для уникальной идентификации устройства лучше использовать комбинацию из кода производителя и серийного номера, если они есть у устройства.

Поскольку Hardware ID - одно из свойств устройства, его можно получить с помощью Setup API. Пример можно посмотреть здесь: [Как программно получить список всех свойств устройства в Device Manager'e?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/752276/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-device-managere)

В Linux, насколько я знаю, нет аналогичного понятия; роль Hardware ID играют пути к виртуальным файлам устройств в подкаталоге `/dev/`.

Comment: Нет, вы не правы в последнем параграфе. Hardware ID на то и **hardware**, что он к ОС не имеет никакого отношения. В данном случае рассматривается пара Vendor ID / Device ID, характерная для многих шин (PCI, USB, ...). Linux тут не причём.

Comment: @0andriy То, что отображается в диспетчере устройств Windows, также не обязано быть физическим устройством, как и dev-файл в Linux. В таком случае у него в Hardware ID может быть произвольная строка. То, что для PS/2-клавиатуры он содержит Vendor ID и Device ID - лишь частный случай.

Comment: Причём тут Windows? Я вам про железо твержу. И если уж быть совсем дотошным, PS/2 устройства не имеют никакого способа сообщить свой идентификатор, даже если он есть внутри.

Comment: @0andriy так у автора в вопросе скриншот из диспетчера устройств Windows...

Comment: Так я не против. Я же комментирую последний абзац вашего ответа. Вы там написали несоответствующие действительности вещи.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй так:

```
sudo lshw -short -c input -numeric
```

это например для класса `input` (мыши, клавиатуры). Можно опустить, тогда выдаст по всем устройствам.

Comment: Это всё равно не то, строки - идентификатора там нет.

Comment: Вот что выдаёт у меня:
03:02.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9227 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:002d] (rev 01)

[168c:002d] - как раз необходимые Ven и Dev и отлично гугляться

Comment: Да дело в том, что мне не гуглить. Вроде бы под win я нашел способ, но его еще предстоит проверить